# sequelize migrations not running

Tags: node.js, orm, graphql, migration, sequelize.js

I'm having a weird issue with Sequelize I haven't encountered before, when I try to run my migrations nothing happens. I get the following output:

```
Loaded configuration file "config\config.json"
Using environment "development"
```

And the program just exists back.

I've checked my code multiple times over and everything checks out.

Model code:

```
module.exports = {
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("users", {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true,
                isEmail: true
            }
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true,
                len: [7, 42]
            }
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
    })
},
down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("users")
}
```

}

And here is a snippet from my model/index.js:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")

const basename = path.basename(__filename)
const env = process.env.TEST_ENV || "development"
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.js`)[env]
const db = {}

console.log('config', config)

let sequelize
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config)
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(
        config.database,
        config.username,
        config.password,
        config
    )
}
```

It's almost like sequelize just isn't picking up any of migrations file. I'm not sure how I should troubleshoot this. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So the issue was with node versions.

I probably should have provided more context to start of with but I switched laptops and on new laptop I had version 14.1.0 installed whereas on old laptop I had version 10.13.0 installed!. So switching versions did the trick.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why version 14 doesn't work (and possible file an issue)?

Comment: No, nothing concrete but I think the issue was that the migrations were initially setup with Node 10.13.0 so when I tried to run them with 14 there was some sort of compatibility issue.

Comment: It seems like this was a compatibility issue between Node 14 and the pg library.  Updating to pg@8.0.3 fixed the issue without needing to downgrade Node.

Comment: @bradley2w1dl Thanks,, having the same issue and npm install --save pg@latest fixed it for me.

Answer (score 19):

Updating `pg` fixed the issue on my end.

```
npm install --save pg@latest
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue as well after updating my node version from 12.16.2 to 14.15.4, suddenly the migrations stopped working with no error message being displayed. To fix this, simply run:

```
npm install pg@latest
```

According to pg's documentation, to use node version >= 14.x you will need to install pg@8.2.x or later due to some internal stream changes on the node 14 branch.

For further reading, look at pg's official documentation [here](https://node-postgres.com/).

Answer (score -3):

try to run this command in your terminal
`sequelize db:migrate:all`

Comment: that command doesn't exist at least in my CLI version 5.5.1

Comment: does not exist in verion 5 ```sequelize db:migrate                        Run pending migrations```